# Adding Events to a Specific Google Calendar in Java

Tags: java, events, google-calendar-api

I have search all over, and I have found bits and pieces on adding events, for .net or php, but not java.

So how do you add events to a google calendar that was created by your program.

Heres what I have
I have is 
CalendarEntry calendar, returned from when I created the calendar.
Entry entry, which is a valid event to be inserted in the calendar I created. 
CalendarService service, which is a valid calendar service.

So based on the calendar variable, I want to generate a url to insert the event at, by calling

```
service.insert(url, entry);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to find an answer from here http://www.danwalmsley.com/2008/09/23/free-sms-service-notifications-using-google-calendar/

String postUrlString = calendarEntry.getLink("alternate", "application/atom+xml").getHref();

Seems to work!

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/gdata/articles/java_client_lib.html):

```
URL postURL = new URL("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/root@gmail.com/private/full");
CalendarEventEntry myEvent = new CalendarEventEntry();

//Set the title and description
myEvent.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Pi Day Party"));
myEvent.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("I am throwing a Pi Day Party!"));

//Create DateTime events and create a When object to hold them, then add 
//the When event to the event
DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2007-03-14T15:00:00-08:00");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDateTime("2007-03-14T17:00:00-08:00");
When eventTimes = new When();
eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
myEvent.addTime(eventTimes);

// POST the request and receive the response:
CalendarEventEntry insertedEntry = myService.insert(postURL, myEvent);
```

And if you already have a `CalendarEntry` (not tested):

```
/* CalendarEntry calendar = ...;  CalendarEventEntry myEvent = ... */
Service myService = calendar.getService();
myService.insert(new URL(calendar.getEditLink().getHref()), yourEvent)
```

Comment: Hmm when I try that code I get the following exception:
com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Invalid request URI

Comment: Could you try with `getSelfLink()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google's Data API for creating events. You can download the java library from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/code.html). The [Developer's guide](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html) can help you get started with using the library.

Here the documentation on creating events: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingEvents

Comment: This post is about adding events to a specific calendar, not the default calendar described in this documentation.